# how to change images on each click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this HTML on my site:

```
 <a id="slick-toggle" href="javascript:change_status()"><img src="img/enable.png"></a>
```

When I click this link, I would like to change the image src to img/disable.png. And revert back to img1.jpg when clicked again & so on. Can someone explain how I do this using jQuery?

Also on each click i want to change my table's column  `emp_ref_table.enabled_flag` value  0 for `disable.png` and 1 for `enable.png` 
Here is my existing jQuery if this helps:

```
function change_status() {
    alert('sure to change the status ?');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('img', this).attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
                return oldSrc == 'img/enable.png' ? 'img/disable.png' : 'img/enable.png';
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `ready` inside function. Where is `e` coming from?

Comment: What is not working by the way ?

Comment: @Rayon image code is not working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/13p901w9/2/

Comment: I EDITED try this inside a seperate `<script></script>`  : `<script>$(document).ready(function() {     
 $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
  alert ('sure to change the status ?');
  e.preventDefault();
  $('img', this).attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
   return oldSrc == 'img/enable.png' ? 'img/disable.png' : 'img/enable.png';
  });
  return false;
 });
});</script>`

Comment: @Braza nothing has changed

Comment: What does the console (F12) on browser says? should show errors in console log. Try using `console.log("message to display");` to help you debug

Comment: @Braza it says anonymous function change_status()

Comment: @Arun that fiddle is not working properly https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/13p901w9/2/

Comment: @ParvezAalam  Does your image is shown when your page is loaded and not changing when you click this link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code : place all your pic changing code in a function:

```js
var changeStatus = false;
            function change_status() {
                var r = window.confirm("Sure to change the status!");
                if (r == true) {
                    if (changeStatus == false) {
                        changeStatus = true;
                        document.getElementById("en-ds").src = "https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg";
                    } else {
                        changeStatus = false;
                        document.getElementById("en-ds").src = "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg";
                    }
                }
            }
```

```html
  <a id="slick-toggle" href="javascript:change_status()"><img id="en-ds" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg">
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the simplified one below, set your enable and disable image paths.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $('img', this).attr('src', function(el, src) {
      var imgEnable = 'http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/australia-day-2014-doodle-4-google-2013-winner-6247445470117888-hp.jpg';
      var imgDisable = 'https://www.google.com/logos/2012/d4g_poland12-hp.jpg';
      return (src == imgEnable) ? imgDisable : imgEnable;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="slick-toggle" href="javascript:;">
  <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/australia-day-2014-doodle-4-google-2013-winner-6247445470117888-hp.jpg">
```